# How to 'Enable CORS' in asp.net web form application?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, ajax

I have developed asp.net web form application and I have need to call cross domain handler, so for that I have need to 'Enable CORS', but I have no idea about that.
I have used 'Enable CORS' with mvc, but not with web form applications,please provide proper suggestion.
Thank you in advance

Comment: Here's your answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35627648/cors-endpoints-on-asp-net-webforms-webmethod-endpoints

Answer (score 0):

```
<httpProtocol>
    <customHeaders>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" values="*" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" values="Content-Type" />
   </customHeaders>
<httpProtocol>
```

Write this code in web.config file at the root of your application.

Comment: thanks for your reply.

I have set up configuration as per your suggestion, but when I have set 
authentication mode is Forms in config file then its not working.


`<authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms defaultUrl="Main.aspx" loginUrl="Login.aspx" name="adAuthCookie" timeout="10" path="/"/>
    </authentication>
    <authorization>`
Please give me suggestion