# ASP.net C# webform ADFS hitting CORS error

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, adfs

I keep hitting CORS error when i want to redirect to ADFS server in webform.
Below are the error that i hit:

[image: CORS error]

I tried few method as mention in below link:
[CORS endpoints on asp.net Webforms [WebMethod] endpoints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35627648/cors-endpoints-on-asp-net-webforms-webmethod-endpoints)

However, nothing is working. Not sure if I missed anything in the ADFS setting?
In my other project that is using MVC, it is working fine. Just the webform keep hitting this error.

Login.aspx.cs

```
protected void LoginSSO(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.AppendHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        Response.AppendHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "*");
        ExternalLogin bUsr = new ExternalLogin();

        HttpContextWrapper contextWrapper = new HttpContextWrapper(this.Context);
        var translator = new ActionResultTranslator(contextWrapper);
        translator.Execute(bUsr.ExternalLoginADFS("ExternalLoginCallback.aspx"));
    }
```

ExternalLogin.aspx.cs

```
public partial class ExternalLogin : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    private const string XsrfKey = "XsrfId";

    public string RedirectUri { get; private set; }

    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult ExternalLoginADFS(string returnUrl)
    {
        return new ChallengeResult(WsFederationAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType, "ExternalLoginCallback.aspx");
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult ExternalLoginADFS(string provider, string returnUrl)
    {
        return new ChallengeResult(provider, "ExternalLoginCallback.aspx");
    }

    internal class ChallengeResult : HttpUnauthorizedResult
    {
        public ChallengeResult(string provider, string redirectUri)
            : this(provider, redirectUri, null)
        {
        }

        public ChallengeResult(string provider, string redirectUri, string userId)
        {
            LoginProvider = provider;
            RedirectUri = redirectUri;
            UserId = userId;
        }

        public string LoginProvider { get; set; }
        public string RedirectUri { get; set; }
        public string UserId { get; set; }
        public Task<ActionResult> Task { get; }

        public class ActionResultTranslator
        {

            HttpContextBase _context;

            public ActionResultTranslator(HttpContextBase context)
            {

                _context = context;
            }
            [HttpGet]
            public void Execute(ActionResult actionResult)
            {

                ControllerContext fakeContext = new ControllerContext();
                fakeContext.HttpContext = _context;

                actionResult.ExecuteResult(fakeContext);
            }
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public override void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
        {
            var properties = new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = RedirectUri };
            if (UserId != null)
            {
                properties.Dictionary[XsrfKey] = UserId;
            }

            context.HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.Challenge(properties, LoginProvider);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you share the code of how you are redirecting to ADFS server from web form?

Comment: I have edited the post with the code.

Comment: I've found that some browsers (maybe Chrome? Firefox? I don't recall) don't like * as the "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value.

Comment: Just from the ADFS side, what version? 2016 has no CORS support - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-fs/operations/customize-http-security-headers-ad-fs

Comment: @rbrayb you are right. after run the powershell script, it does solve the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the solution.

Solution:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-fs/operations/customize-http-security-headers-ad-fs

Run the PowerShell script to enable it

[image]